# take csv data from webpage directly in R

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I want take financial data form this site
https://www.cryptodatadownload.com
The direct link https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/Binance_BTCUSDT_1h.csv

Now i just manually download .csv file and then  read in R

```
reticulate::use_condaenv("r-tensorflow")
library(data.table)
library(keras)
library(ggplot2)
dt <- fread("Binance_BTCUSDT_1h.csv", skip = 1)
dt
```

How get data from this direct link?

Comment: read.csv can also read from a url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read.csv` or for that matter `fread` as well accepts url as an argument. You can do

```
read.csv("https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/Binance_BTCUSDT_1h.csv", skip = 1)
```

Or with `data.table::fread`

```
fread("https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/cdd/Binance_BTCUSDT_1h.csv", skip = 1)
```

Comment: Can someone help with this data on Kaggle:                                                  https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data                      I tried with this code:  data<-read.csv("https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data?select=test.csv", skip = 1)